# Calling a method for memory allocation c++

Tags: c++

Does doing the following, create memory problems (new allocations without proper deletes)
Assuming an object named "object"

```
class aClass
 { 
private:
    object* myobject;
public:
    aClass() : myobject(NULL) {};
    ~aClass() 
         {
            if(myobject)
               delete myobject;
             myobject = NULL;
         }
    void myfuction() 
       {
          if(myobject)
             myobject = new object();
       }
 }
```

does calling myfunction() often create memory which is never released, or the fact that i create the variable and copy it to myobject is safe, because at the end the myobject gets deleted ?

Comment: In it's current form, myfunction will never allocate any memory.

Comment: Why ? above i said, assuming object is defined. Which means once its constructor is called , it is created.

Comment: Because `if(myobject)` won't ever become `true` and should actually be `if(!myobject)`.

Comment: Good point, but there is a leak ? yet in the bottom you asserted there is none. ??? thnks

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  i see,  you're saying in its current form, there is no leak, but if `if(!myobject)` is written then, there will be a leak. correct ?

Comment: @SamGomari no, because once called, myobject will no longer be `NULL` so `if (!myobject)` will always evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does calling `myfunction()` often create memory which is never released,

Currently as this function is written, it would never allocate any memory at all, since you have (correctly) initialized the pointer in your constructor:

```
aClass() : myobject(NULL) {};
                 // ^^^^
```

so the condition in `myfunction()`

```
if(myobject)
```

will never be met, supposed the only code where memory allocation is done for `myobject` is in `myfunction()`.

> or the fact that i create the variable and copy it to myobject is safe, because at the end the myobject gets deleted ?

Well, calling `delete` for a `NULL` pointer is transparent and won't ever fail.

---

Actually I think you want to write `myfunction()` like this:

```
void myfuction() {
    if(!myobject)
    // ^ Check if myobject is NULL
         myobject = new object();
}
```

The destructor will correctly delete the allocated memory as soon the `aClass` instance goes out of scope.

But be aware of the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and other operations that would affect assignments to the `myobject` member.

Comment: thanks , Is `if(myobect == NULL)` the same as `if(myobject)` or opposite ?  ,

Comment: @SamGomari These are opposite actually, `if(myobject)` is equivalent to `if(myobject != NULL)`.